# Diff entre dois commits

Tags: git, foreach, diff

Estou fazendo um `git diff` entre dois commits e em geral ele me mostra a diferença entre os arquivos que foram modificados nesses commits.

EX:

```
git diff 1a1a1a 4d4d4d

+              Essa linha foi adicionada
-              Essa linha foi removidada
```

Isso funciona perfeitamente, e nada tenho a reclamar. A questão é que entre esses commits existem outros commits! E é exatamente eles que eu quero.

Ex:

```
commit 1a1a1a
Author: Gabriel Hardoim

     Commit 1A

commit 2b2b2b
Author: Gabriel Hardoim

     Commit 2B      // Esse commit me interessa

commit 3c3c3c
Author: Gabriel Hardoim

     Commit 3C      // Esse também

commit 4d4d4d
Author: Gabriel Hardoim

     Commit 4D
```

Tendo isso em mente, como posso fazer um `for each` entre o primeiro e o último commit? O git tem algum comando que possa me ajudar nesse caso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use o `..` entre os commits:

```
git diff 1a1a1a..4d4d4d
```

[Ou](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3368758/2387977):

```
git diff 1a1a1a^..4d4d4d
```

Se deseja incluir as diferenças do commit inicial `1a1a1a`.

Sem o `..`, você pega apenas as diferenças entre **somente** os dois commits e não de todos os commits entre eles.